# how to make background color animate to new color and back without losing track of original color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

So I am trying to create a simple animation that takes the background from the initial color to the new color and back.

The original issue I had is that I created a trigger on the MouseDownEvent that triggered the animation, but the user could trigger another animation before the first one finished. This new animation would animate from the current shade it was at to the new color and back. By progressively restarting the animation while the animation is going, the original color is lost.

The easiest way to solve this is probably if i use the completed event for the animation. However, I don't like this solution because I want my animations to be in a custom style in resource dictionary and not part of the control itself. If the animation is in a custom style in a resource dictionary, then it won't have access to the code behind of the control itself.  Is there a good way to get an animation working while maintaining separation between the style and the control?

I then had a different idea. The error is caused because I was animating from the border.background.color to a new color and back, thus if i started a new animation while the old one was going, the new animation started from whatever color value the prior animation was in.  But if I set the animation to go back to some saved property value of the original background color then I won't have the issue even if the user restarts the animation.

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:Components="clr-namespace:DaedalusGraphViewer.Components"
                xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:DaedalusGraphViewer.Components.Converters"
                >
     <Converters:ThicknessToLeftThicknessConverter x:Key="ThicknessToLeftThicknessConverter" />

  <Style x:Key="SearchBoxListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>


  <Style x:Key="{x:Type Components:SearchBox}" TargetType="{x:Type Components:SearchBox}">    
    <Style.Resources>

    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Components:SearchBox}">
            <Border x:Name="Border"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ScrollViewer 
                x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                />
              <Label 
                x:Name="DefaultTextLabel"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TextColor}"
                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelText}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontStyle="Italic"
                />




              <Popup x:Name="RecentSearchesPopup"
                     IsOpen="False"
                     >
                <ListView 
                  x:Name="PreviousSearchesListView"
                  ListView.ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SearchBoxListViewItemStyle}" 
                  >
                </ListView>
              </Popup>

              <Border 
                x:Name="PreviousSearchesBorder"
                Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="LightGray"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness, 
                Converter={StaticResource ThicknessToLeftThicknessConverter}}"
                >
                <Image 
                  x:Name="PreviousSearchesIcon"
                  ToolTip="Previous Searches"
                  Width="15"
                  Height="15" 
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Source="pack://application:,,,/DaedalusGraphViewer;component/Images/Previous.png" 
                  />
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasText" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="DefaultTextLabel" Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger 
              SourceName="DefaultTextLabel"
              Property="IsMouseOver" 
              Value="True" 
              >
              <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam" />
            </Trigger>

            <!--<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown" SourceName="PreviousSearchesBorder">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation 
                      AutoReverse="True"
                      Duration="0:0:0.2"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousSearchesBorder"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).Color"
                      To="Black"
                      />
                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>-->


            <Trigger Property="IsPopupOpening" Value="True">
              <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                      Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousSearchesBorder"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).Color"
                      >
                      <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{x:Static Components:SearchBox.DefaultRecentSearchesButtonColor}" />
                      <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Black" />
                      <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="{x:Static Components:SearchBox.DefaultRecentSearchesButtonColor}" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <!--<ColorAnimation 
                      AutoReverse="True"
                      Duration="0:0:0.2"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousSearchesBorder"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).Color"
                      To="Black"
                      />-->
                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
              </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
```

However, in order to do this I need to store the original background property and I have yet to get that working. I cannot using binding because properties in Animations must be freezeable, so I tried creating a static property on the control that gets set to the original value on the control's loaded event.

I set the color to the background color in the code behind, but the style does not reflect that property.

Is my static reference in the xaml correct? if so, then isn't onapplytemplate when the style should load the color from the static reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all I ended up doing was using FillBehavior = Stop. I was new to animations so I didn't know how to prevent the reactivation of the animation easily without access to the completed event (which would have to be attached in the control, thus defeating the purpose of having a style with animations in a separate resource file).  Regardless, I'm giving the bounty to rhyous because his answer actually does solve my problem as well, though in a more difficult manner. I knew that what i wanted to do had to be simple because there was no way that no one had wanted to animate a color and back from a style, yet I couldn't find any Stack Overflow questions on the issue

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't use a DynamicResource without getting a Freeze error.

What if you loaded the Xaml file at runtime and added the StaticResource to the Xaml file?

Here is an example. (I use some quick and dirty parsing of the Xaml file, but it works for the proof of concept.)

Change the properties of the StoryBoardResourceDictionary.xaml to Content and Copy if newer and remove the MSBuild:Compile setting.

**StoryBoardResourceDictionary.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="WindowWithTrigger" TargetType="Window">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" >
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="White"/>
                                <!-- OriginalBackground is added at runtime -->
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="{StaticResource OriginalBackground}"/> <!-- Load at runtime -->
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="BackgroundAnimationBlend.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480" 
    Style="{DynamicResource WindowWithTrigger}"
    Background="DarkBlue"> <!--Change background to whatever color you want -->
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace BackgroundAnimationBlend
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var rd2 = LoadFromFile();
            this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd2);
        }

        public ResourceDictionary LoadFromFile()
        {
            const string file = "Styles/StoryBoardResourceDictionary.xaml";

            if (!File.Exists(file))
                return null;

            using (var fs = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string xaml = string.Empty;
                string line;
                bool replaced = false;
                while ((line = fs.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!replaced)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("OriginalBackground"))
                        {
                            xaml += string.Format("<Color x:Key=\"OriginalBackground\">{0}</Color>", Background);
                            replaced = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    xaml += line;
                }
                // Read in an EnhancedResourceDictionary File or preferably an GlobalizationResourceDictionary file
                return XamlReader.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xaml))) as ResourceDictionary;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to scale this right now. So maybe it is a crazy idea. But loading the style at runtime and injecting the current background as a xaml string into the style before loading it is the only idea I had that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small example to illustrate how you can solve your problem (by what i have understood).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="background">yellow</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="backgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource background}"/>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Black"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{StaticResource background}"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{StaticResource backgroundBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}" Name="Storyboard1"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

I have defined a Color *background* as StaticResource to use it as Background-Color for the Grid and as Value for the Animation.

In the example above the Grid has a yellow background, that gets animated to black and then back to yellow when the button is clicked.

Comment: so i'm guessing to use this I need to get the original background color and store it in the style's resource?

Comment: I updated the original post, but i'm wondering whether what i want is even possible. I just wanted to be able to generically define animations within the style that is saved in a resource dictionary instead of inside the control itself.   I mean an animation is a slight visual modification, not a change in the control. yet it's the control that has access to the original animation color.  

I don't think I can save the original color as a static resource in the resource dictionary.

Comment: I had thought I could make the control get the original color of the button at runtime and save it as a property so that it could be referenced from the style, but I don't see how to do that.